Touchpad driver for VEN_0488:00 0488:Touchpad on Debian 12 - Dell Precision 5480
What is the touchpad device (does not react but no bootstrap log errors as it seems):
VEN_0488:00 0488:Touchpad

I tried this configuration but without success:
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
    Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
    Option "DisableWhileTyping" "on"
    Option "ClickMethod" "clickfinger"
    Option "ScrollMethod" "twofinger"
EndSection


In the dmesg log I see:
[    1.633732] input: VEN_0488:00 0488:1031 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-VEN_0488:00/0018:0488:1031.0001/input/input7
[   53.153719] input: VEN_0488:00 0488:1031 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c


